# How to trigger an alert in Google Cloud monitoring when a condition is violated only during a specific time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, time, google-cloud-monitoring

We have a requirement to trigger an alert if a file is not available in a folder in GCS storage bucket at a particular time everyday. We have created a log based metric to capture the log entry for successful upload. How can I make the alert condition to be checked only at the specific time everyday?

There is no option available in alerting console, is this possible through MQL? I could not find anything helpful in the documentation

Comment: AFAIK, you can't.

Comment: it should totally be possible to create a periodic function in MQL, also you can play with intervals. What are the conditions you are looking for ?

Comment: @c69 The requirement is to check for a file availability at 2 AM everyday and trigger an alert if condition is violated (i.e file is not available in bucket) at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Google cloud team confirmed that it is not possible to check condition only at specific time range.
We achieved the expected behavior by writing custom metric data point at a scheduled time and configuring an alert policy on this metric.

Answer (score 0):

The [alert condition](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts#specifying_logs-based_metrics) for the log based metric is not unable to be checked only at the specific time everyday.

Please review the MQL documents for your scenario:
[`Monitoring Query Language reference`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference)
[`Alerting policies with MQL`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/alerts)
[`Using the Query Editor`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/query-editor)
[`Examples of MQL`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples)